# Why I can't get values from this web service Array?

Tags: arrays, json, session, for-loop

Can't figure out why this web service don't work. Just gives me blank. I tested the url and the data it's all there.

http://onleague.stormrise.pt:8031/OnLeagueRest/resources/onleague/News/News?id_user=a7664093-502e-4d2b-bf30-25a2b26d6021&page=1&new_filter=0

my code:

```
session_start();
function getNews() {
    $json = file_get_contents('http://onleague.stormrise.pt:8031/OnLeagueRest/resources/onleague/News/News?id_user=a7664093-502e-4d2b-bf30-25a2b26d6021&page=1&new_filter=0');
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $newst = array(); 
    foreach($data['data']['item'] as $item) {
        $newst[] = $item;
    }
    foreach($newst as $v) 
    {
        $_SESSION['newsid'][] = $v['id'];
        $_SESSION['newstitle'][] = $v['title'];
        $_SESSION['newstext'][] = $v['news'];
        $_SESSION['newslink'][] = $v['link'];
        $_SESSION['newsdate'][] = $v['date'];
        $_SESSION['newsentityName'][] = $v['entityName'];
        $_SESSION['aclikes'][] = $v['account']['likes'] . ")";
        $_SESSION['acdislikes'][] = $v['account']['dislikes'] . ")";
        $_SESSION['accomentes'][] = $v['account']['commentes'] . ")";
        $_SESSION['acshares'][] = $v['account']['shares'] . ")";
        $_SESSION['acclicks'][] = $v['account']['clicks'] . ")";
    }

}
getNews();
$key = count($_SESSION['newsid']);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $key; $i++) {
        echo $_SESSION['newsid'][$i] . "<br />";
    }
```

Comment: It just gives me blank instead of display the newsid value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that this line is correct:

```
foreach($data['data']['item'] as $item) {
    $newst[] = $item;
}
```

Reading this makes me think that you are overwriting the entire $newst array with a single item... for each item. Thus the array will end up being the value of the *last* $item (which might be empty).
I'd expect something like:

```
foreach($data['data']['item'] as $item) {
    $newst.push( $item );
}
```

(note, not tested and my syntax may be dodgy... but you get the drift).